# Can't schedule python script with crontab

Tags: python, cron, schedule

## I have this python script I did in anaconda and downloaded to my local workspace as .py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[33]:


#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""This example downloads a criteria performance report as a string with AWQL.

To get report fields, run get_report_fields.py.

The LoadFromStorage method is pulling credentials and properties from a
"googleads.yaml" file. By default, it looks for this file in your home
directory. For more information, see the "Caching authentication information"
section of our README.

"""


from googleads import adwords
import io
import pandas as pd


adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

  # Initialize appropriate service.
report_downloader = adwords_client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')

  # Create report query.
report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                .Select('CampaignId', 'AdGroupId', 'Id', 'Criteria',
                          'CriteriaType', 'FinalUrls', 'Impressions', 'Clicks',
                          'Cost')
                .From('CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                .Where('Status').In('ENABLED', 'PAUSED')
                .During('LAST_7_DAYS')
                .Build())
    
output = io.StringIO()
    
report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
      report_query, 'CSV', output, skip_report_header=True,
      skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=True,
      include_zero_impressions=True)

output.seek(0)


df = pd.read_csv(output)
    
print(df.head())


# In[44]:


df.to_csv("/Users/ezerivarola/Desktop/Google_ADS_API/report1.csv",index=False)


# In[ ]:
```

and I am trying to schedule it with crontab with the following command:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/ezerivarola/Desktop/Google_ADS_API/Report1_DF.py
```

But, although I don't get any error and when looking at mail I see it is running, the csv file of the script is not being generated.

Does any one have an idea of what can it be wrong?

Comment: If you manually run the execute it from the terminal for you does it run? /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/ezerivarola/Desktop/Google_ADS_API/Report1_DF.py

Comment: Yes, it executes perfectly

Comment: Have you tried by specifying user in the cron command ? Something like.                     



* * * * * user /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/ezerivarola/Desktop/Google_ADS_API/Report1_DF.py

Comment: I tried this: * * * * * ezerivarola /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/ezerivarola/Desktop/Google_ADS_API/Report1_DF.py. but nothing occurred

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the 5 *'s at the beginning to match the time period in which you want it to run,

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                   7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * command to execute
```

The below will run it every hour on the hour,

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/ezerivarola/Desktop/Google_ADS_API/Report1_DF.py
```

Comment: I understand this, but I am using * * * * * to refresh data every minute to test it works.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem. Crontab was not executing python script because it did't have access to disk. I leave a link with more details of de solution: https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/

thank you all